# how to find out the exact threshold value for the correct recognition of person

Tags: matlab, pca, dwt

hello I am novice here in matlab my task is to write a code for multimodal biometric system using discrete wavelet transform and pca (principle component analysis) for 100 people database containing 9 face, 2 ear and 2 thumbprint images.
for same I wrote following code for each sample

```
E11=imread('E1(1).JPG');
E11=imresize(E11,[100 100]);
E11=rgb2gray(E11);
%colormap(pink)
[a,b,c,d]=dwt2(E11,'haar');
X=a;E11=X(:);
E11=im2double(E11);
for reading all those images
```

after that i applied pca on all these images and after it i used the minimum distance classifier 
    mindist=dist(i);

```
for i=2:10
    if dist(i)< mindist
        mindist=dist(i);
    end
end

for i=1:10
    if dist(i)== mindist
        img=i;
        break;
    end   
end

disp(['Recognized image number as class................']);
disp(img);

if dist(img)>=600;
    img=i;
end
```

like this of course before this i had found weight vectors and all after this i had wrote switch case for identifying the person

```
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(y), title('Image to be Recognized'),colormap(gray);
subplot(1,2,2)
x1=imresize(x1,[100,100]);
imshow(x1), title('Recognized Image'),colormap(gray);
toc
and the above last code is for recognising that image
```

now my question is al this code works well for 5 classes showing correct output for 70%(no.of correct images/total no. of images) but i have to extend this code for 100 people it shows very less accuracy how can i do this please guide me i will be very grateful to you for same

Comment: I dont think there is a way of doin git perfectly I am afraid.... PhD thesis are writen about these topics...

Comment: what should i do then??:(

Comment: a PhD thesis? I dont know I am afraid. There is no "perfect" way of doing it. Try different methods, research the literature,... There is just not a simple answer to this